# Stuck on understanding using a local_thread_storage object(std::aligned_storage) for logging

Tags: c++, multithreading, logging, iostream, glog

I am recently reading the code of [glog](https://github.com/google/glog) for building a custom log module later.

Basically, usage is as follows:

```
#define LOG(SERVERITY) LogMessage(SERVERITY).stream()

const char* log;
...
LOG(INFO)<<log<<endl;
```

I extracted some key [lines](https://github.com/google/glog/blob/master/src/logging.cc#L1364-L1470) of code as follows:

```
class LogStream : public std::ostream {
...
}

class LogMessage{
...
public:
    LogMessage() : allocated_(NULL) {
      Init(...);
    }
    ostream& LogMessage::stream() {
       return data_->stream_;
    }
    struct LogMessageData;
...
private:
    void Init(...);
    LogMessageData* allocated_;
    LogMessageData* data_;
...
};

struct LogMessage::LogMessageData{
...
LogStream stream_;
...
};

static __thread bool thread_data_available = true;
static __thread std::aligned_storage<sizeof(LogMessageData), 
                                    alignof(LogMessageData)>::type thread_msg_data;

void LogMessage::Init(...){
    if (thread_data_available) {
          thread_data_available = false;
          data_ = new (&thread_msg_data) LogMessageData;
    }else {
          allocated_ = new LogMessageData();
          data_ = allocated_;
    }
//initialize each field of LogMessageData
...
}

LogMessage::~LogMessage() {
...
  if (data_ == static_cast<void*>(&thread_msg_data)) {
    data_->~LogMessageData();
    thread_data_available = true;
  }
  else {
    delete allocated_;
  }
}
```

To my understanding, `thread_msg_data` is used as pre-allocated buffer to avoid frequent memory allocation and deallocation in a local thread, so what is `allocated_` used for? It seems `allocated_` will be used only when the last logging task not finished in the same thread(Maybe a huge chunk of data is still in the stream buffer and waits to be written to the destination, which locks `thread_msg_data`?)